# I want to update a value of radio button in database (mysql) using php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am new to php and mysql. i've used radio buttons to save the type of my account records i can insert the data successfully but when i try to get that data (whether type S is selected or type T is selected) from sql to update it further i cant do that. i dont know how to get the data of radio buttons from my sql.. please help

```
<form method="post" action="users-edit-action.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $accountid; ?>" name="id" />
    <label>Email/Username:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /><br /><br />
    <label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>" /><br /><br />
    <label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" /><br /><br />
    <label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" /><br /><br />
    <label>Type:</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="<?php echo $type; ?>" /> Student<br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="<?php echo $type; ?>" /> Teacher<br />

        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    </form>
```

this is how i get the value from database.. im sure iam doing wrong, please help me solve this..

Comment: Where do the values of your variables (`$accountid`, `$email`, `$password`, etc) come from?

Comment: <?php include("../includes/config.php"); ?>
<?php
 if ($_SESSION["isadmin"])
   {

   $con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$accountid=$_GET["id"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (id='".$accountid."')");


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $id=$row['id'];
       $firstname = $row['firstname'];
       $lastname = $row['lastname'];
       $email=$row['email'];
       $type=$row['type'];
    }
mysql_close($con);
?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to check which type you got from the database and according to that add this attribute to the input element: `checked="checked"`. So the whole selected tag would look like this:

`<input name="type" type="radio" checked="checked" value="the one PHP returned" />`

And the other input tag would also be there, but without the `checked` attribute.
You just need to do the PHP check on what element to put the attribute.

The whole part:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="S" <?php if ($type == 'S') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>" /> Student<br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="T" <?php if ($type == 'T') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>" /> Teacher<br />
```

Comment: i couldnt get that..how would i do that??

Comment: Someone didn't like it... there, I gave you a +

Comment: oww thanx :) i think i'll be able to manage it when i get used to it

Comment: Yeah, it's not hard really - the community is very well organized.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your radio-buttons is fixed and does not depend on the value in the database, only whether it is checked or not.

It should be something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="S" <?php echo ($type == 'S') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> /> Student<br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="T" <?php echo ($type == 'T') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> /> Teacher<br />
```