# Update mysql with radio select php

Tags: php, html, mysql, syntax, echo

Ok guys this is driving me nuts. Maybe its the monday morning but I just can't get this right:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="choice.php">
<table border="1px">
<tr>
<?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($id);
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo '<td><img src="images/smiley.jpg" alt="Chose me"><br><input type="radio" name="choice" value='.$id <?php if ( $choice == $id ) {echo "checked";} ?>.' >Chose me</td>';

    }
?>
</tr>
</table>
<br class="clear" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<br class="clear" /> 
</form>
</body>
```

The problem is with this:

```
echo '<td><img src="images/smiley.jpg" alt="Chose me"><br><input type="radio" name="choice" value='.$id <?php if ( $choice == $id ) {echo "checked";} ?>.' >Chose me</td>';
```

I have read these (but still can't get the syntax right):

[I want to update a value of radio button in database (mysql) using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151718/i-want-to-update-a-value-of-radio-button-in-database-mysql-using-php)

[php update radio button state in db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615121/php-update-radio-button-state-in-db)

I think that the problem is with single and double quotes. Tried changing them all around and still get get various Parse errors: for unexpected ? or > and so on

Even tried to move this part

```
<?php if ( $choice == $id ) {echo "checked";} ?>
```

to a separate line, and managed to get a valid php file that way, but when I copy it back to the echo statement it always screws up.

Pretty please tell me the right way.

Comment: try this `echo '<td><img src="images/smiley.jpg" alt="Chose me"><br><input type="radio" name="choice" value="'.$id.'" '.($choice == $id?'checked':'').'" >Chose me</td>';`

Comment: the problem is that you add `<?php ?>` inside the `<?php ?>`

Comment: Also, where are you getting the value of *$choice* from? There should be something in a field somewhere from your DB query that specifies if something has already been specified as the "choice."

Comment: Ok, my bad. this is what you get when you do not explain things right. So what I am trying to achieve is to put the id corresponding to the selected radio button into $_POST. This should be a family who picks who for xmas. Each id is a family member. It should be and id so you do not know who you are chosing.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Actually Mark's answer works. Just forgot to upload the file to the website. Sorry, I donno where my mind is...

Answer (score 0):

is this line correct `$id <?php if ( $choice == $id ) {echo "checked";} ?>`?? you're trying to put the checked attribute inside the value? or what you mean is this

```
  $checked = $choice == $id ? "checked" : null;
  echo "<td><img src='images/smiley.jpg alt='Chose me'><br><input type='radio name='choice value='{$id}' {$checked}>Chose me</td>";
```

note that i alter the use of single quote to double quote so that you can use variables in side double quotes

Comment: No. (At least not intentionally)

Comment: Thanks Semi-Friends, but no, not really. What I am trying to achieve is that there is a small form with 4-10 radio buttons each representing an id from a mysql database. (Each representing a family member) When the submit button is pressed I wish to write todays date to mysql where the id = the selected radio value. I have read in the mentioned posts that this is done through setting the checked state of the radio button.